# External monitor has no signal unless entered BIOS first

Tags: graphics-card, bios, hdmi, msi-laptop

## Problem Description

I have a laptop with an nvidia graphics card, and is trying to connect to an external monitor.

- The laptop is a MSI GS65 stealth thin 8RE, dual booted with windows 10 + ubuntu 22.04. The behavior is consistent for both systems.
- The monitor is Dell S2721QS 27 Inch 4K UHD

I tried to plugin an external monitor to it's HDMI port. Although the computer thinks there is a monitor connected, the monitor itself shows "HDMI 1/2 has no signal". This behavior doesn't happen for the other mini-dp port and usb-c port on the laptop.

Although for some odd reason, the external monitor receives signal if i first briefly enter the BIOS before booting into my OS (linux or windows here)

I'm hoping someone whom may have encountered a similar issue can provide some insight :D

## Fixes Attempted

### Doesn't Work

1. boot up straight into OS **with** HDMI connected (tested with both Windows and Ubuntu)
   Disconnected - Reconnected HDMI multiple times
2. Boot up straight into OS **without** HDMI (tested with both Windows and Ubuntu)
   Disconnected - Reconnected HDMI multiple times
3. Tested difference between duplicate screen, extend screen, display only on one (tested with both Windows and Ubuntu)
4. In Ubuntu, updated nvidia-driver to 535 (tested under 525 and 535), tested nvidia-prime profile to performance, on-demand
5. turned on/off fast boot in BIOS.

### Partially Works

1. Connected to mini - DP port / USB C port. This works, but the monitor only display on 30Hz. My suspicion is that those two ports are not HDMI 1: [link to reference](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/4k-monitor-wont-display-60hz.3574478/)
2. Boot into bios, then into OS. This is currently my best solution.

## My Guess

I have some odd feeling that some graphics driver for the external graphics card is not properly initialized if i boot directly into the OS. Perhaps the two ports that does work is actually connected to the motherboard and the HDMI is connected to the graphics card?

Given my issue is OS agnostic, this feels like a hardware specific issue related to my MSI laptop. I not sure how I can prove this, nor do i see any options in my BIOS that I can play around with related to graphics card.

Edit: Added tests done, added specification for the monitor,  added that this is a dual boot system.

Comment: Just to verify, the laptop screen still works regardless, correct? What if you duplicate the laptop screen to the external monitor without going into the BIOS? And what if you disconnect, reboot, connect from within windows? And what if you disconnect/reconnect the cable itself?

Comment: What are the intended resolutions for the monitors?

Comment: @LPClip yes the laptop screen still works. I updated the post to reflect some of the quick fixes that I tried.

Comment: @harrymc the intended resolution for the monitor is 4k 60hz (external) and 1920x1080 144hz(native laptop)

Comment: Try as a test to lower the resolutions and frequencies.